# Composition using JPA and deletion

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, eclipselink

I have one `Role` that can refer to a Set of `Permission`s.

How can I annotate both classes to fit composition (not aggregation) where:

- A `Permission` continues to exist if a `Role` is
  deleted ?
- A `Role` continues to exist if it has no `Permission`s.

P.S: How should this be handled with merging/persisting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `ManyToMany` relationship annotated with `@ManyToMany`. If it is required to have a `unidirectional ManyToMany` then just annotate the member field or getter method (depending on the access type field or property respectively) of the `Role` class related to `Permission`. If you need `bidirectional` relationship then you will have to annotate both classes and specify the `mappedBy` annotation attribute on the non-owning/target side, the `Permission` class.

To achieve this relationship a `join table` will be created if not already exists ( if it exists a `@JoinTable` may be required to specify exact table name and column names).

Regarding persistence and merging, when a `Role` persists/merges the associated `Permissions` will also be persisted/merged and the associated entries in the join table will be created as in a many-to-many relationship the owner side actions are cascaded by default (the owner side is the side without the `mappedBy` attribute).

So the setup for a bidirectional many-to-many would be something like,

```
@Entity
public class Role {
....
 @ManyToMany
    private Set<Permission> permissions;
....


@Entity
public class Permission{
.....
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="permissions")
    private List<Role> roles;
....
```

also check out the spec http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-spec/index.html
and this wonderful book http://www.apress.com/9781430219569